# Pulse secure is not working from 18.04

Tags: 18.04, vpn

I have installed pulse secure in ubuntu 18.04.when i am trying to connect the login window is coming, but after giving the credentials the window is disappearing. Can anyone tell me what is causing this ?

Comment: What is "pulse secure"?

Comment: a third party software to connect to a network

Answer (score 1):

I had several similar issues:

**Problem:**
The "libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file" is because the dependencies have not been installed

**Solution:**
Follow the quick start guide, specifically

- 64 bit machines

  ```
  /usr/local/pulse/PulseClient_x86_64.sh install_dependency_packages
  ```
- 32 bit machines:

  ```
  /usr/local/pulse/PulseClient.sh install_dependency_packages
  ```

**Problem:**
Not being able to find "libgnome-keyring.so.0", this was because libgnome-keyring installed as "libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0"

**Solution:**
Create a sym link, for me this command worked:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0
```

**Problem:**
The credentials window disapears. This was because the setup created the following folder using the "root" user.

```
~/.pulse_secure
```

**Solution:**
Change the ownership of the folder to the current user.

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.pulse_secure
```

The Linux quick start guide [can be found here](https://www-prev.pulsesecure.net/techpubs/pulse-client/pulse-secure-client-desktop).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue for weeks. I even tried to switch kernel version but nothing worked out.
Today, I have resolved this issue.

Solution:

Run your pulse secure client with root permissions (only when you add/edit a connection)

`sudo /local/user/pulse/pulseUi`

(Assuming your pulse secure path is default installation path)

Also, make sure you install all the dependencies.

Comment: ./pulseUi: error while loading shared libraries: libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1220165/937696